# mariadb bug al hacer json_object

Tags: json, mariadb

Si ejecuto la siguiente instrucción en MariaDB:

```
select JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('anyo', g.anyo, 'ene', g.ene, 'feb', g.feb)) as xxx from gastos g
```

todo funciona ok, obtengo el resultado correcto. Por ejemplo:

```
[{"anyo": 2019, "ene": 368.80, "feb": 368.80},{"anyo": 2019, "ene": 283.30, "feb": 283.30}]
```

En cambio, al hacer esto otro:

```
select json_object('desc', d.descripcion, 'd_id', d._id,
    'valo', (select  JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('anyo', g.anyo, 'ene', g.ene, 'feb', g.feb)) as xxx from gastos g where g.descripcion_id = d._id)
) as yyy from descripciones d
```

Me aparecen un simbolos backslash junto a las comillas pero no en todas:

```
{"desc": "Gas", "d_id": 26, "valo": "[{\\\"anyo\\\": 2019, \\\"ene\\\": 233.40, \\\"feb\\\": 0.00},{\\\"anyo\": 2020, \\\"ene\\\": 193.30, \\\"feb\\\": 0.00}]"}
```

Me pone el array entre comillas ¿?

El error se produce porque incluye barras invertidas dobles: este es el resultado con cadenas de escape:

```
'{\\"desc\\": \\"Gas\\", \\"d_id\\": 26, \\"valo\\": \\"[{\\\\\\"anyo\\\\\\": 2019, \\\\\\"ene\\\\\\": 233.40, \\\\\\"feb\\\\\\": 0.00},{\\\\\\"anyo\\\\\\": 2020, \\\\\\"ene\\\\\\": 193.30, \\\\\\"feb\\\\\\": 0.00}]\\\"}'
```

ACTUALIZADO: lo he probado en Mysql ver.8.0.23 y funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve el mismo problema en MySQL (5.7), si bien no es la misma tecnología te daré una recomendación que podría funcionar independiente del motor de bd

**Recomendación**: Recorre la sub-consulta y por cada elemento has un PUSH al arreglo.

Crea un ciclo o un cursor para recorrer

```
select  JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('anyo', g.anyo, 'ene', g.ene, 'feb', g.feb)) as xxx from gastos g where g.descripcion_id = d._id)
```

En lugar de agregar todo el resultado directo al json final, crea un JSON_OBJECT por cada iteración, guarda el objeto en una variable temporal y has un push al arreglo ubicado en el json final antes de hacer la siguiente iteración.

Ese push puede ser de manera similar a como lo haces en

```
select JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('anyo', g.anyo, 'ene', g.ene, 'feb', g.feb)) as xxx from gastos g
```

Solo que con el equivalente a un PUSH a un arreglo json.

Espero haberme dado a entender con claridad.

Comment: Pues en este caso en Mysql ver.8.0.23 funciona correctamente. Lo acabo de probar y devuelve la query de forma totalmente correcta.